# iOS taking login id from setting not from app login

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, facebook

I am facing problem while Facebook post from ios app.

In iOS there is made 2 ways login 1st is from setting in iPhone and other is from app.

When i am post any thing to facebook through Xcode at that time it is taking facebook login id from settings facebook login not from app login.

I want facebook login id which is used in app login not setting.

Is there any solution for this problem.

Comment: Would taking out the use of Facebook in the Settings app and don't use it at all be a solution ? If you're already using the Facebook iOS SDK, it's probably better to just use that. It really isn't worth it from the past experience we had. Not many people have Facebook signed in to their settings, some of our users were even confused and didn't know where to put the login in the Settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ar using `UIActivity Controller` for sharing, then it will take the Setting login ID, If you need to take the app login then you may have to implement your own custom method for sharing on Facebook using, Facebook SDk,

You can refer the below link for implementing your own share

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share
```